# CSS Selector for a TD in a Table with an ID

Tags: java, html, css, css-selectors, jsoup

I have an html table with an ID of `thetable`. It has (according to FireBug), an unnamed TBODY tag, and an unnamed TR tag. The three TD tags inside that I want to access are unnamed. Is there any CSS selector that I can use to reference these unnamed tr tags?

I've tried:

`table#thetable:nth-child(1)`

But this does not select for those tags.

I'm using [jsoup.org](http://www.jsoup.org) to pull this data into strings. I'd like to take the text of each TD in the table (of which I know the name) and put all that into an array.

Something like this:

```
// Pseudocode for all the TDs into an array
Elements strings = doc.select("table#thetable: children");
```

Comment: nth-child in your example refers to tables that are nth-child of their parent (not the children of the table).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're simply looking to get all your `td` elements, this should be enough:

```
Elements elems = doc.select("table#thetable td");
```

Then iterate `elems`, retrieve the text from your `td`s and put them in your array.

Also, you should probably use an array list instead of an array if you don't know or can't control how many cells your table will have:

```
Elements elems = doc.select("table#thetable td");
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Element e : elems) {
    strings.add(e.text());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You didn't need to add that second part :) I just had trouble figuring out how to get all the table elements with the CSS selector in Jsoup. Thanks again and sorry, I should've been clear about the parsing part from the beginning.

Comment: No problem. I haven't written any Java code in forever, so I'm just taking this opportunity to... revise ;)

Answer (score 6):

You just want to access all of the cells?

```css
#thetable td
```

Or do you just want to access the first row?

```css
#thetable tr:first-of-type td
```

Comment: I should probably also say that I'm parsing HTML in Java using [Jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org). Will that produce an array then?

Comment: @Mark Lyons: Yes. Even if no elements are matched, the list should be empty, but not null.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have been more specific. Please take a look at the edit I just made.

Comment: Here's what I have: `Elements table = doc.select("#thetable tr:first-of-type td");`

Comment: @MarkLyons: Is it working? EDIT: You have an extra `tr` there. Is that intentional?

Comment: I removed the tr. Unfortunately that did not work, look at BoltClock's answer. Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough about what I was trying to do, but I really appreciate the help from you and Bolt.

Comment: @MarkLyons: No problem. And y'know, my first selector works the same as his ;) `#thetable td`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. This targets the first row of TD cells, excludes the header row:

http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/hGRwc/1/

```
table#thetable tr:nth-child(1) td{ /*Edit Here*/ }
```

Ive included some other examples in the css for you